# i keep getting error 404 while trying to create a blog using django with the djangogirls tutorial

Tags: python, django

i keep getting an error (404) page when i run my server for a django when i click the link to a post detail. I think nothing is wrong with my code so i need help to locate why i'm getting the error.

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog2app/home_post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request,    pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,  pk=pk)
    return render(request,  'blog2app/postdetail.html', {{'post': post}})
```

```
this is my blog2app\urls.py
```

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
   path(r'^$', views.post_list, name="homepage"),
   path(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail,  name='post_detail'),
]
```

this is my blog2/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^$', include('blog2app.urls')),
]
```

this is my home_post_list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <p><h4>Published: {{ post.published_date }}</h4></p>
    <h1><strong><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}"> {{ post.title }} </a></strong></h1><br>

    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

this is my detailpost.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{%  if  post.published_date %}
{{  post.published_date }}
{% endif %}
<h1>{{  post.title  }}</h1>
<p>{{   post.body|linebreaksbr  }}

</body>
</html>
```

```
this is the error page on chrome.
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in blog2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/$
^$
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page
```

the development server is showing no error.

blog2app is my app name.
blog2 is my projectname.
i am using pycharm idle for development.

i will be very happy if anyone can suggest any tutorial video particularly for creating blogs with django.

Comment: can you please provide details of the error....

Comment: is your appname blog2app? can you open list view correctly?

Comment: Remove the `$` from `path(r'^$', include('blog2app.urls'))`. `$` means end of string, meaning url ends there and `post/<pk>/` is striped.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my detailpost.html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{  posts.published_date    }}
<h1>{{  posts.title }}</h1>
<p>{{   posts.body|linebreaksbr }}
</body>
</html>
```

i changed my views.py to

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog2app/home_post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk=None ):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'posts': post}
    return render(request,  'blog2app/postdetail.html', context)
```

i changed my home_post_list.html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <p><h4>Published: {{ post.published_date }}</h4></p>
    <h1><strong><a href="{% url 'post_detail_pk' pk=post.pk %}"> {{ post.title }} </a></strong></h1><br>

    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

and i stopped seeing the error.
My conclusion is i was using the post in

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

to call my primary key instead of using posts in

```
context = {'posts': post}
```

Max Goodridge django tutorial really helped me.